# mkdir -p /catkin_ws/src is not working

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I have just installed ROS noetic on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using multimass (so I am in a virtual enviroment in windows).

I am folowing the ROS tutorial step by step and after the installation there is the creation of a Workspace using catkin, but the first command to do that ("mkdir -p /catkin_ws/src") doesn't work.

The response is:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/catkin_ws’: Permission denied
```

How can I fix that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371509/mkdir--p-/catkin_ws/src-is-not-working/) by [andreatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69733/andreatesta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> mkdir -p /catkin_ws/src
> ```

you're missing the `~` (or tilde), which refers to your home directory on Linux.

Right now you're trying to create a directory in the root of your filesystem, which is typically not something you can do as an ordinary user.

You'll want to run something like this:

```
mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
```

or (equivalent):

```
mkdir -p $HOME/catkin_ws/src
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andreatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69733/andreatesta/) on 2021-02-10**:
Thanks a lot! Actually in the tutorial the ~ was present but I cannot write it in Windows powershell (even copying and pasting it doesn't appear). With $HOME instead it works!!!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-10**:
The tutorials will assume you're using Bash, so I'm not surprised the commands don't work for you in PowerShell.

I'm also slightly confused how you're using PowerShell on Ubuntu.

**Comment by [andreatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69733/andreatesta/) on 2021-02-10**:
I am not on Ubuntu, but on Windows 10. To create the virtual machine needed to generate an Ubuntu enviroment I used Multipass. So Windows Powershell is available.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-10**:
Multipass creates VMs afaict. So it's still Ubuntu that's eventually running.

You state so yourself as well.

**Comment by [andreatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69733/andreatesta/) on 2021-02-11**:
Yes but the terminal where I am writing remains the same, the tops rows are still:

```
    Windows PowerShell
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tutti i diritti riservati.
    
    Prova la nuova PowerShell multipiattaforma https://aka.ms/pscore6
    
    PS C:\Users\Utente>
```